# How to use data-toggle in ActionLink using jquery or within ActionLink()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
       <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home1">ApplicantProcess</a></li>
       <li class="tab-red">@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", "ProcessApplicant", new {@id="AppliId",href="/ProcessApplicant/Create",data_toggle="tab" })</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the thing here is that I want data_toggle also come within ActionLink.
If try using jquery

```
$('#Applicant').click(function () {
    $(this).prop('href', '/ProcessApplicant/Create');
});
```

I get Syntax error within console. I am using tabs and when a specific tab is clicked I am rendering a partial view within the particular tab. I even tried without href attribute within ActionLink() but doesn't works.Plz help me how to have an ActionLink with data_toggle attribute within tab. Thanks for reading

Comment: Why do you have `new { href="/ProcessApplicant/Create" ..}` when the `ActionLink()` method already adds it?

Answer (score 0):

The most easy solution will be to replace `Html.ActionLink` with an `<a>` tag and and you can set the desired attributes.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "ProcessApplicant")" id="AppliId" data-toggle="tab">Create</a>
```

To render the `PartialView` within the tab that was `click` you can use something like this. (this is based on your code, there are others way to do it).

```
$('#myTab li a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function () {
    event.preventDefault(); // use to prevent navigating to other page
    var $anchor = $(this); // take the anchor that contains the partial view href

    var href = $anchor.attr('href');

    $.get(href, function (data) { // call the action that will return PartialView
        $('#tabContent').html(data + href); // replace with the content of PartialView
    });
});
```

**Note:** 
You don't need to specify `href="/ProcessApplicant/Create"` inside `Html.ActionLink`, it will already build the `href` dynamic based on existing routes.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to mention HTML attributes with hyphen, is using dictionary object. Like this,

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
       <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home1">ApplicantProcess</a></li>
       <li class="tab-red">@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", "ProcessApplicant", new Dictionary<string,Object> { {"id","AppliId"}, {"data_toggle","tab"} })</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hope it helps, Thank you.